# How to create conda environment with yml file without this error?

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, conda

I am following the [here](https://www.guru99.com/pyspark-tutorial.html) tutorial to do PySpark on AWS.

My Os: macOS High Sierra 10.12.6

Up until now everything worked as in the tutorial.

I have successfully created the the "hello-spark.yml" file and opened it in sublime text and the edited parts are right there as well.

I get the error message when I run the following code:
`conda env create -f hello-spark.yml`

```
myComputerName anaconda3 MyPersonalName$ conda env create -f hello-spark.yml

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1043, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 73, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 77, in execute
        directory=os.getcwd())
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/specs/__init__.py", line 40, in detect
        if spec.can_handle():
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/specs/yaml_file.py", line 18, in can_handle
        self._environment = env.from_file(self.filename)
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/env.py", line 144, in from_file
        return from_yaml(yamlstr, filename=filename)
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/env.py", line 129, in from_yaml
        data = yaml_load_standard(yamlstr)
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 76, in yaml_load_standard
        return yaml.load(string, Loader=yaml.Loader, version="1.2")
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/main.py", line 640, in load
        return loader._constructor.get_single_data()  # type: ignore
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/constructor.py", line 102, in get_single_data
        node = self.composer.get_single_node()
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/composer.py", line 75, in get_single_node
        document = self.compose_document()
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/composer.py", line 96, in compose_document
        node = self.compose_node(None, None)
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/composer.py", line 132, in compose_node
        node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/composer.py", line 187, in compose_mapping_node
        while not self.parser.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/parser.py", line 144, in check_event
        self.current_event = self.state()
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/parser.py", line 547, in parse_block_mapping_key
        if self.scanner.check_token(KeyToken):
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/scanner.py", line 160, in check_token
        self.fetch_more_tokens()
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/scanner.py", line 273, in fetch_more_tokens
        return self.fetch_value()
      File "/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/scanner.py", line 626, in fetch_value
        self.reader.get_mark())
    ruamel_yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
      in "<unicode string>", line 2, column 17:
            dependencies:
                        ^ (line: 2)

`$ /Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/bin/conda-env create -f hello-spark.yml`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
  CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false
        CONDA_BACKUP_HOST=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                     PATH=/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/bin:/Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/bin:/U
                          sers/macbookair13/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/u
                          sr/local/bin:/Users/macbookair13/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:
                          /bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/macbookair13/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/macbookair13/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/macbookair13/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.5
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /Users/macbookair13/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/macbookair13/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/macbookair13/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/macbookair13/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Darwin/16.7.0 OSX/10.12.6
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]:
```

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: macOS High Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original post creates the .yml file as follows:

```
name: hello-spark 
    dependencies:

    - python=3.6
    - jupyter
    - ipython
    - numpy
    - numpy-base
    - pandas
    - py4j
    - pyspark
    - pytz
```

The correct way to do so is:

```
name: hello-spark 
dependencies:
    - python=3.6
    - jupyter
    - ipython
    - numpy
    - numpy-base
    - pandas
    - py4j
    - pyspark
    - pytz
```

If you are unsure how to edit in vi just use sublime text or any other code editor.